# Windows 8 Store Error code 0xc03f40c8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I recently converted the account on my Surface Pro 3 from a Microsoft account to a local account (because I was tired of typing in a password for each and every user). However, since doing this, I am unable to install any apps from the Microsoft Store. Even apps I already own.

I get the following error:

```
Your purchase couldn't be completed
Something happened and your purchase can't be completed.
Error code: 0xc03f40c8
```

Now searching around the web I have seen several solutions, none of them have worked. These are what I've tried doing:

- Restarting the Windows Update service.
- Running `WSReset.exe` as an Administrator.
- Syncing Windows Store App Licenses.
- Converting account back to a Microsoft account.
- Converting account back to a local account.

What does this error mean and how can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was easier than I thought, nothing of the posted above helped me, after spending over 4 hours trying to find out a solution. What I did to solve the problem “Your purchase couldn’t be completed
Something happened and your purchase can't be completed.
Error code: 0xc03f40c8)” is the following:

1. Go to https://account.microsoft.com/about
2. You will find this message (One account for all things Microsoft
   Sign in to manage your info, your purchases, your family’s devices, your security and privacy. It’s all tied together with your Microsoft account), click sign in
3. Make sure you sign in with the same account you are using on your stores

And the problem is solved, I am downloading now many apps.